# Optimizing USB tethering

Tags: network-interface, internet

I'm running Arch Linux (kernel 4.17.2-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jun 16 11:08:59 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux). I have consistently slow speeds on SpeedTest.net while using USB tethering.

As part of my troubleshooting, I used the same Android phone with the same setings at the same location (and even the same USB cable) and tested USB tethered speeds on a Windows 10 laptop. (Both laptops are ThinkPads. One runs Arch Linux, one runs Windows 10.)

What I noticed is that USB tethering speeds are significantly faster on Windows 10. As a next step, I would like to tune my connection parameters on Linux to match the speeds I am seeing on Windows 10. What are the steps?

I am also searching for steps to determine what the connection parameters are on Windows. The Windows command:

```
netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces
```

shows that the MTU is 1500, so nothing special there.On Linux `ip a` also shows an MTU of 1500 for the tethered interface. If the speed difference is not due to MTU, what else might be affecting it?

By the way, the Linux laptop has very good Internet speeds over all interfaces (both wired and wireless) for all connections other than USB tethering. The connectivity for USB tethering is not the problem. It is the slow speeds. My carrier says I am not being throttled and the testing on Windows confirms that. So the slow USB tethering speeds are related to Linux, but it is not a general problem with all networking. It is limited to USB tethering only.