# Quirky USB Tethering

Tags: networking, usb, network-interface, android, internet

On my Arch Linux machine I have selectively slow connections to some particular resources, for example: to Arch repositories (100 KiB/s, tops), to a Minecraft server or to anything—I couldn't find the pattern. In the same time, I can watch a YT video in 1080p at double speed with no delay; Steam games are downloading at a normal speed, and my ping is about 70 in Steam games. Why so?

I'd managed to find two other cables at home, I tried them with no positive result.

In addition to my PC, I have a laptop that runs Arch Linux too. On it, I tested the cables, but with no result again. So I've tried WiFi tethering and it works just fine: I had decent speeds when I was downloading updates, also a nice ping in that MC server. Sadly, I don't have a WiFi-adapter for my PC.

What could it be? I'm really frustrated. I have no clue. My ISP keeps saying that they do not slow any connections (unless it's a torrent traffic in the prime time).

Here is what *dmesg* shows about the USB port I tether via:

```
[   37.013378] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[   37.136713] usb 2-4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[   37.391008] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2008, bcdDevice= 2.23
[   37.391019] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   37.391025] usb 2-4: Product: Nokia 2.2
[   37.391029] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[   37.391033] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
[   47.913876] usb 2-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   48.320044] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[   48.467582] usb 2-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=2004, bcdDevice= 2.23
[   48.467593] usb 2-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   48.467599] usb 2-4: Product: Nokia 2.2
[   48.467602] usb 2-4: Manufacturer: HMD Global
[   48.467606] usb 2-4: SerialNumber: HZAL1670CAJ61222625
[   48.541141] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[   48.547950] rndis_host 2-4:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:13.2-4, RNDIS device, 22:b2:27:1c:e5:2a
[   48.547977] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[   48.557346] rndis_host 2-4:1.0 enp0s19f2u4: renamed from usb0
```

Here you can check [the full log](https://pastebin.com/JSi4pce0).

Here is the output of *ifconfig*:

```
enp0s19f2u4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.254.80  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.254.255
        inet6 fe80::dfd9:c54e:3974:c2b4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 66:6e:50:e9:4c:f7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 58563  bytes 65194672 (62.1 MiB)
        RX errors 10  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 10
        TX packets 43491  bytes 6523802 (6.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp3s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 90:2b:34:96:0c:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 15  bytes 2006 (1.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 2006 (1.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

Also, do check [this super-related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452705/optimizing-usb-tethering) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1331768/usb-tethering-much-slower-than-wifi-tethering/1733242#1733242).

Comment: "My ISP keeps saying that they do not slow any connections" My ISP (orange) keeps telling the same when it's obviously not true.  (many demonstrations made particularly in covid-lockdown times when many started working from home)

Comment: Can you clarify how USB tethering comes into it? How exactly are you connecting the PC to the network?

Comment: @terdon I'm sorry, isn't it obvious? I connect my phone to the PC via USB cable, then I toggle `USB tethering` option in Android settings, then, I guess, NetworkManager (I forgot to mention it in the question) handles the rest and I get the Internet.

Comment: @MC68020 They say that they can't do it, because it isn't stated in my contract (I'm not sure what it is properly called in Enlgish). I don't mean that this ensures that they do not slow connection, but still.

Comment: Did you try accessing accessing those "problematic resources" via whatever (non)-free anonymous VPN ?

Comment: @MC68020 I thought to do it, but, unfortunately, I'm too dumb to properly install one on my PC, but I have OpenVPN and SocksDroid on my phone. I am not sure if the traffic from my machine will go through them. I will try some free servers (and only free, because I can't afford to pay for it).

Comment: @MC68020 I couldn't think that it will be so hard to find a free working config for OpenVPN. I've managed it, but it seems that it applies only to the phone's traffic. I guess I should try to install OpenVPN on my PC.

Comment: @MC68020 I've installed OpenVPN, but I can't test anything because of the slowness of a free VPN server that I found. It's much easier to find free decent proxies. Well, I will try to find another server later.

Comment: @MC68020 no offense, but the symptoms shown here seem to have very little to do with ISPs throttling. You're making a lot of very bold statements there!